# Bigquery Get json key name

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that contains a column that contains a JSON string. Within the JSON, there may be a key called "person" or "corp" or "sme". I want to run a query that will return which of the possible keys exist in the JSON and store it in a new column.

Below is the data from a column 'class', which is one long string each in BQ.  The first level key name can equal ‘corp’, ’sme’, or ‘person’ (see examples below).

Example 1

```
{
  "corp": {
    "address": {
      "city": "London",
      "countryCode": "gb",
      "streetAddress": [
        "Fairlop road"
      ],
      "zip": "e111bn"
    },
    "cin": 1234567420,
    "title": "Demo Corp"
  }
}
```

Example 2

```
{
  "person": {
    "address": {
      "city": "Madrid",
      "countryCode": "es",
      "streetAddress": [
        "Some street 1"
      ],
      "zip": "z1123ab"
    },
    "cin": 1234567411,
    "title": "Demo Person"
  }
}
```

I've tried using the json_xxx functions, but they require specifying the json_path.  I'm interested in fetching the json_path name to create a new column (cust_type)which lists corp, sme, person for each row.

| example | cust_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | corp |
| 2 | person |

This is my first question so pls bear with me! Thnx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ... I'm not yet following the question.  Don't worry about being verbose if it helps.  I see two example JSON fragments that appear to majorly differ by the field/key name corp vs person.  I'm not seeing how this relates to BigQuery?  Are you trying to load data into a BQ table?  Are you trying to create a new BQ table?   Maybe show some more sample inputs and the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks @Kolban.  It might help with some background. The original json was sent thru an ELT pipeline service then loaded to Bigquery. I' centralizing data sources (everything from marketing, ie google ads, to dbs, ie mongodb which is where the json file comes).  So the data is already loaded into BQ.  In BQ, the column 'class' contains the unpacked json fragments and it's one long string (like below). 
{"corp": {"address": {"city": "London","countryCode": "gb","streetAddress": ["Fairlop road"],"zip": "e111bn"},"cin": 1234567420,"title": "Demo Corp"}}

Comment: Ahhh .... thank you!!!   So to play it back ... the question becomes .... "I have a BigQuery table that contains a column that contains a JSON string.  Within the JSON, there may be a key called "person" or "corp" or "sme".   I want to run a query that will return which of the possible keys exist in the JSON."

Comment: Yes @Kolban! I updated the original post. TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we can use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function and look to see if the field exists (is not null).  An example test might be:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.corp') is not null then 'corp'
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.person') is not null then 'person'
    WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.sme') is not null then 'sme'
  END AS cust_type
FROM UNNEST([
  '{"corp": {"address": {"city": "London","countryCode": "gb","streetAddress": ["Fairlop road"],"zip": "e111bn"},"cin": 1234567420,"title": "Demo Corp"}}',
  '{"person": {"address": {"city": "Madrid","countryCode": "es","streetAddress": ["Some street 1"],"zip": "z1123ab"},"cin": 1234567411,"title": "Demo Person"}}'
  ]) AS json_text;
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked well!  Thanks for your help with the solution and guidance when posting questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a function to extract first level keys whatever they are.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_keys(input STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRING> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input))
""";

SELECT json_keys(json_text) AS cust_type
  FROM UNNEST([
  '{"corp": {"address": {"city": "London","countryCode": "gb","streetAddress": ["Fairlop road"],"zip": "e111bn"},"cin": 1234567420,"title": "Demo Corp"}}',
  '{"person": {"address": {"city": "Madrid","countryCode": "es","streetAddress": ["Some street 1"],"zip": "z1123ab"},"cin": 1234567411,"title": "Demo Person"}}'
  ]) AS json_text;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Didn't realize BigQuery supported javascript as a language for SQL functions. Very cool!